# Copy or Delete columns with names assigned in 1st row. Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy

```
ID      Student Name
34534   22222   Block Project
56653   11111   Rocket Science
12222   33333   Big Bang Project
13245   44465   Explosive Science
88888   59833   Audio Analytics
```

The above are just a mini portray of the data as I have over 80 columns of data. Since we can be editing or adding columns anytime in between, how can I add or delete the columns with the name based on the first row of data? 
Deletion:

```
Dim vNoCopy As Variant, v As Long
    vNoCopy = Array(5, 6, 7, 11, 13)
    With altwb.Sheets("CRIMS_ams_report_all_ccr")
        For v = UBound(vNoCopy) To LBound(vNoCopy) Step -1
            .Columns(vNoCopy(v)).EntireColumn.Delete
        Next v
        .Copy After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)
    End With
```

So in deletion, I'm declaring the position of the column using numbers and delete it accordingly. Is it possible to change the array of numbers as the first row of the words? (Id, Student, name etc.)
Addition:

```
data.Columns("A").Copy .Range("A" & myCount)        'Change Columns("A") into something like student? ID?
```

The copy of columns is pretty simple. Any shortcut for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the column's ordinal (number) with `Application.Match` and use that to identify the column(s) to delete.

```
Dim vNoCopy As Variant, v As Long
vNoCopy = Array("Name", "Student", "Id")
With altwb.Sheets("CRIMS_ams_report_all_ccr")
    For v = UBound(vNoCopy) To LBound(vNoCopy) Step -1
        if cbool(application.countif(.rows(1), vNoCopy(v))) then _
            .Columns(application.match(vNoCopy(v), .rows(1), 0)).EntireColumn.Delete
    Next v
    .Copy After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)
End With
```

That assumes no misspelling (but can be non-case-sensitive) and that the column exists. I've added `COUNTIF` to check that the column exists before attempting to remove it. Without the check, any failure would crash the procedure.

Comment: You're a really helpful person. +1 cookie